# How can I run ros-indigo-husky-desktop on Jade?

Tags: husky, ros-jade, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I have installed ROS Jade on Ubuntu, and I faced the problem on this tutorial: http://wiki.ros.org/husky_control/Tutorials/Interfacing%20with%20Husky .

```
$ sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-husky-desktop
```

command works fine, but

```
$ roslaunch husky_viz view_robot.launch
```

generates the following problem:

```
[view_robot.launch] is neither a launch file in package [husky_viz] nor is [husky_viz] a launch file name
The traceback for the exception was written to the log file
```

I would be grateful for your help.

Best!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/224717/how-can-i-run-ros-indigo-husky-desktop-on-jade?/) by [Paulo123](https://answers.ros.org/users/25683/paulo123/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-01-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You cannot install packages under *Indigo* and then try to use them in *Jade*. Those are two separate ROS distributions.

You'll have to ask the maintainers of the `ros-indigo-husky-*` packages to release them into Jade, or try to build them from source in a catkin workspace.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2016-01-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tonybaltovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/3462/tonybaltovski/) on 2016-01-21**:
I'll ping the maintainer.  Is there a reason for using Jade?